# jQuery check if the last three data attributes are equal to

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say this is the HTML:

```
<div id="chat">
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div> 
  <div class="msg" data-user="3">bla</div> 
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div>
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div>
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div> 
</div>
```

How do I check if the last three `user attributes` are `7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nth-last-child selector in combination with attribute selector:

```js
var is = $('.msg:nth-last-child(-n+3)[data-user=7]').length === 3;

if (is) {
    console.log('last 3 messages has data-user 7');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat">
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div> 
  <div class="msg" data-user="3">bla</div> 
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div>
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div>
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.slice()` , `.get()` , `Array.prototype.every()`

```js
var res = $("#chat .msg").slice(-3).get().every(function(val) {
  return val.dataset.user === "7"
});

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat">
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div> 
  <div class="msg" data-user="3">bla</div> 
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div>
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div>
  <div class="msg" data-user="7">bla</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution works great too, thanks, too bad you can't accept more than one answer ^^

Comment: @petertausend No worries dfsq's solution is briefer. Could probably adjust above to use attributes selector as well `$("#chat .msg").slice(-3).is("[data-user=7]")`